# Windows 10: Fault type errors change from 4 to 5 after several steps. Why?

Tags: windows, exception, fault

I have an application that I developed that is only affecting some Windows 10 users but not all of them. The application would open then immediately shut down. I saw in the event viewer that it produced an Application Error 1000, Fault Type 4 error when this happens. I looked up some information and did several steps, including SFC, clean booting, reinstalling .NET Framework, etc. None of that worked. Then randomly out of habit I defragmented my drive and suddenly the application now opens. It still produces an Application Error 1000, but type 5 this time. It does not affect the application performance whatsoever.

My question is this: Why? And what can I do to ensure this does not happen for users of this application?

I am posting the actual error details below.

Fault 4 error cycle:

```
Fault bucket 1923725877593378771, type 4
Event Name: APPCRASH
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: Interstream_Windows.exe
P2: 8.0.8.58005
P3: 5d44b1d2
P4: Interstream_Windows.exe
P5: 8.0.8.58005
P6: 5d44b1d2
P7: c0000005
P8: 000000000090a90f
P9: 
P10: 

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: e67385ca-22aa-4211-9cf4-ed3fc989c5e1
Report Status: 268435456
Hashed bucket: c712bd3c5c6c3c2d6ab2727e4b2e0fd3
Cab Guid: 0


This is accompanied by:
Faulting application name: Interstream_Windows.exe, version: 8.0.8.58005, time stamp: 0x5d44b1d2
Faulting module name: Interstream_Windows.exe, version: 8.0.8.58005, time stamp: 0x5d44b1d2
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000000000090a90f
Faulting process id: 0x58dc
Faulting application start time: 0x01d9213ffe2c75f1
Faulting application path: C:\Users\jbernagozzi\Desktop\Interstream_Windows\Interstream_Windows.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Users\jbernagozzi\Desktop\Interstream_Windows\Interstream_Windows.exe
Report Id: e67385ca-22aa-4211-9cf4-ed3fc989c5e1
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID: 


Fault 5 is different, here is this code:   
Fault bucket 1733984756823260336, type 5
Event Name: BEX64
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: Interstream_Windows.exe
P2: 8.0.8.58005
P3: 5d44b1d2
P4: ucrtbase.dll
P5: 10.0.18362.1110
P6: b4cacc38
P7: 000000000006dace
P8: c0000409
P9: 0000000000000007
P10: 

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: 5c9cea6d-60d0-4b5f-ad90-99be23184f85
Report Status: 268435456
Hashed bucket: 66ccab7de70f21c6181059f304647cb0
```

accompanied by:

```
Faulting application name: Interstream_Windows.exe, version: 8.0.8.58005, time stamp: 0x5d44b1d2
Faulting module name: ucrtbase.dll, version: 10.0.18362.1110, time stamp: 0xb4cacc38
Exception code: 0xc0000409
Fault offset: 0x000000000006dace
Faulting process id: 0x1678
Faulting application start time: 0x01d9216b9f3abbe8
Faulting application path: C:\Users\jbernagozzi\Desktop\Interstream_Windows\Interstream_Windows.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll
Report Id: 5c9cea6d-60d0-4b5f-ad90-99be23184f85
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

It is strange how different the codes are. Why?

Comment: Apparently, the error is nondeterminstic. Sometimes the program crashes with an invalid pointer. Sometimes the pointer happens to be valid "enough" that it doesn't crash immediately, but crashes later because an invalid parameter was passed to a C++ function.

Comment: As to why, we can only guess. Raymond Chan gave one possibility. As to how to ensure this doesn't happen to all of your users - what is different between the systems you've tested your application on? Is it the same version of Windows, same version of VC Redist, do the users have elevated / admin privileges, etc? How are you handling your exceptions? Are you logging them anywhere when they are triggered (writing to a file, etc)?

Comment: @FiddlingAway It's highly likely that the environment is only incidental. There is a memory management bug in the program that it sometimes gets away with and sometimes doesn't. ASLR means that memory layouts are always changing, so sometimes you're lucky and sometimes you aren't.

Comment: @FiddlingAway It is completely random. It seems that Windows 11 users are unaffected unless they fiddled with their TPM to get Windows 11. Otherwise, there is no common issue. I am on Win 10 version 1903 and so is another user. I had this issue and as I described above, randomly when I defragged it became totally fine and hasn't had an issue. This is not the case of the other user. Running as admin doesn't do anything, neither does playing with permissions.

Comment: @RaymondChen Stangely enough, it isn't throwing up any more errors now. It went from fault 4 to 5 and now is not throwing up any faults. Beyond random layouts, why would it change from having faults to not?

Comment: Uninitialized memory can result in sporadic failures.